# Is there a way of viewing the columns for relationships within pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've begun populating the following tables inside my database:

```
class ModelItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'

    name = Column('name', String, primary_key=True)
    set_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('set.name'))
```

```
class ModelSet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'set'

    name = Column('name', String, primary_key=True)
    items = relationship('ModelItem', backref='set')
```

Everything seems to be working fine since I can query the children of the parent record and come up with the expected data within my code. I'm just wondering if there's a way to see that same `items` column in pgAdmin like I can with all the other columns for the parent table

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A SQL statement that joins the two tables? If yes, you should [edit] your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables. I for one can't tell how exactly the tables look like from that code.

Comment: I just want to know if I can somehow view the `items` column within the `set` table in pgAdmin since I can't seem to find it anywhere amongst the other columns

Comment: Sure, just write a SELECT statement that joins both tables.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, I'm a bit new to this. I know I can query the data. I find the column fine doing it like that. I'm just wondering if that same `set` column I can view through a query is viewable within the gui. 

Or as you saying that this is suppose to be something I do in pgAdmin in which case I really don't understand.

Comment: I think your looking for a built in schema/object browser within pgAdmin4.  Well if so open pgAdmin, then in the browser pane. Select: Server -> Database -> Schema ->Tables -. Select interested table -> right click -> properties.